# Is the "++" operation atomic in C?

Tags: c, operators, atomic

I am trying to determine whether or not a statement like:

```
++value;   //assuming "value" is a **global** variable
```

is an atomic operation.

I need to know if this calculation is capable of being interrupted by an Interrupt Service Routine that writes to the same global variable.

Comment: Write a quick test and see. Then tell me because I'm lazy ;).  Just increment a shared variable 100 times with 2 or 3 threads.  If the variable isn't the correct value, the operation isn't atomic.

Comment: I'm sort of guessing here but I would say that normally it is a single machine code statement, but that there is no guarantee about this for every possible C compiler.

Comment: @WilliamMorrison And your quick test will prove beyond any doubt that that operation is atomic in all cases, on every architecture you might target with this code? shakoldo44: The answer to your question is architecture dependent. To make sure it always works, declare `value` as [`_Atomic`](http://en.cppreference.com/w/c/atomic).

Comment: @JonathanWood: Not really, even for a single work, `++` is not a single instruction, the value needs to be loaded into a register, incremented in the register and pushed back to memory (if loading/storing is necessary -- if done in a loop the compiler might skip stores and lead to even crazier values)

Comment: @JonathanWood: It may be a single instruction (e.g. `inc` on x86), but it's *still* not atomic. You'd need something like `lock inc` in order for it to be atomic.

Comment: @WilliamMorrison Writing a "quick test" for synchronization questions like this is not good advice. You need to be able to *look* a solution and *know* it is correct, because "quick tests" like you suggest are often completely incapable of detecting subtle race conditions caused by details like this.

Comment: OP is likely concerned with a single architecture. Also, a test to determine whether this operation is atomic is practicle because this is NOT a subtle tricky case. Run 1kk iterations with multiple threads. If the count is correct, the operation is atomic. Don't overcomplicate a simple problem people.

Comment: @DavidRodríguez-dribeas: Are you certain that all processors allow an interrupt to occur within a single machine instruction?

Comment: @JonathanWood: I never claimed that, I only stated that `++p` in c++ code is not a single assembly instruction, it is a sequence of *load `p` into register*, *increment register*, *store back into `p`*. Those are three instructions, two threads can read the same value of `p`, increment it independently and store `p+1` back to memory, with the overall appearance of a single increment (not 2). Addionally, they may cache the value in the register, then one thread incrementing 100 times might store just to see the value clobbered by a different thread that incremented once...

Comment: @DavidRodríguez-dribeas: First off, you did claim that `it may be a single instruction but it's still not atomic`. And I want to know how you know this is true across platforms. Second, as far as it not being a single assembly instruction, on the platforms I'm familiar with, it is.

Comment: @JonathanWood: You  are confusing me with Kerrek :)

Comment: @DavidRodríguez-dribeas: You are correct sir, sorry about that. (Note that an increment can be done in a single machine instruction though, at least on the x86.)

Comment: @JonathanWood: I am not sure that you can `inc` from memory, and I am not sure how `add` with the destination in memory could be atomic (it needs to load the value from memory to the processor, operate and write back to memory...)

Comment: @DavidRodríguez-dribeas: On the x86, you can both increment and add to values in memory. I would imagine the current generation provide even more flexibility than what I'm familiar with.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

On objects without an atomic type, standard never defines ++ as an atomic operation.

C11 defines atomic types in stdatomic.h.
If you have an object with an atomic type, a *postfix* and *prefix* operators `++` will define an atomic operation as: *read-modify-write operation with memory_order_seq_cst
memory order semantics.*

You can also use atomic_fetch_add() if you want an atomic increment.

Comment: I will treat the ++ operation as a non-atomic operation.  i.e. disable interrupts before the operation and re-enable afterwards.  I had a hunch that it was a "Read-Modify-Write" kind of situation as ++value can also be written as value = value +1.  -Thank You

Comment: @shakoldo44 What architecture are you working on? Your CPU may have an instruction to accomplish this without disabling interrupts (e.g. `lock inc` on x86).

Comment: The last paragraph is wrong. `++` on `_Atomic` objects is an atomic operation with `seq_cst` ordering semantics.

Comment: @2501: Prefix `++` is equivalent to `+=1`, which is also atomic; see 6.5.16.2 Compound assignment, paragraph 3. And yes it's confusing that you have to follow through that equivalence to find out that it's atomic when reading the standard.