# Atomicity of the simple assignment operator

Tags: c, standards, language-lawyer, atomic, c11

C11 Standard says that for atomic types (_Atomic), prefix and postfix `++` and `--` operations [are atomic](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/26900404/is-the-operation-atomic-in-c/26900455#26900455) (6.5.2.4.,p2), as are compound assignments: `op=` (6.5.16.2,p3).

I haven't found anything written about a simple assignment `=`. Is it also atomic?

Let's says E1, E2 are `int`, but only E1 is defined with the specifier _Atomic. 
My assumption is that this:

```
E1 = E2;
```

is equivalent to:

```
atomic_store( &E1 , E2 );
```

It my assumption correct?

Comment: How can this _not_ be atomic. What state is between 'set' and 'not set' ?

Comment: @WernerVanBelle This is from the perspective of the Standard. Imagine an abstract machine.

Comment: @WernerVanBelle On Atmel with avr-gcc, for example, when you set a 16-bit variable, first the high byte then the low byte is set.

Comment: @Ctx: There are many other such examples. Not sure if there is `stdatomic` support for AVR, though. Also IIRC there is information (i.e. `#define`s) available which types/widths are actually supported as atomics.

Comment: I suspect this case is covered by 6.2.6.1/9, "Loads  and  stores  of  objects  with  atomic  types  are  done  with `memory_order_seq_cst` semantics."  . The cases of `++` and compound-assignment needed special treatment because there is both a read and a write of the same atomic involved

Comment: @WernerVanBelle Say, half the bits are written but not the other half, giving a nonsense value.

Comment: @Olaf, if a platform supports stdatomic it does so for all data types that are not arrays. If there is direct support in form of atomic *instructions* on the level of the processor, these are usually *lock-free*. If not they are emulated by the library. There are macros in stdatomic to check for these properties.

Comment: @MM, can you elaborate your comment into an answer, please?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Following the example in this [Dr Dobbs article](http://www.drdobbs.com/cpp/c-finally-gets-a-new-standard/232800444), **simple assignment of atomic variables in C11 is atomic**.

The C11 standard (ISO/IEC 9899:2011), section 6.2.6.1/9 reads:

> Loads and stores of objects with atomic types are done with
>   `memory_order_seq_cst` semantics.

In addition to being atomic, operations performed with `memory_order_seq_cst` semantics have a single ordering observed by all threads (aka [sequentially-consistent ordering](http://en.cppreference.com/w/c/atomic/memory_order)).

Without the `_Atomic` type qualifier, it is possible for an assignment to be non-atomic. Assigning a 64 bit value (e.g. a `long long`) on a 32 bit machine requires two CPU cycles. If another thread reads the value between those two cycles they'll get 4 bytes of the old value and 4 bytes of the new value.